# self join issue, i think?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have one table(could only have one) that looks like seen below.

It contains a plant code, an article number and batches related to that article.

```
plant - code - batch - value - volume - added_date
A1      1000   A1      10      20       date
A1      2000   A7      20      15       date
A1      1000   A1      5       10       later than first A1 batch
A2      200    A8      10      9        date
A1      2000   A10     20      20       date
```

How could I present this information like this: for each plant and code, show the `DISTINCT` number of batches and the volume for only the latest added batch(note that code 1000 in `plant A1` is showing only 10 as that is the volume of the latest added batch).

```
plant - code - batches - volume
  A1      1000   1         10     
  A1      2000   2         35
  A2      200    1         9
```

I got some help from a guy here earlier, and that query works great until I tried to get the volume from only the latest batches if there is two batches with same number for the same product on the same plant.

```
SELECT code, plant,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(batch)) as Batches,
    SUM(value) as TotalValue,
    SUM(volume) as TotalVolume,
    SUM(value * risk) as TotalRisk,
FROM lists 
GROUP BY code, plant
```

I guess you could do it with some concat and self joins but I am not skilled enough to work with only one table :/

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Well, actually the answer that Adrian linked to solved the described issue...however it seems to be to hard to do make everything else work with that solution. I did only describe a part of my "problem", what I thought was enough to then solve the rest myself. But I was wrong. Not only do I need the latest added batch and volume, I also need to do some SUM operations on the batches. I am thinking that it may be best for me to place the data into two different tables and work from there.

Comment: You have on your hands a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem. I lack the time to write a tailor-made answer for you, so take your time to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/570191 . It will guide you to the right answer

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I will read that! First I was afraid you would say that there was no solution for my problem :)

Comment: Don't worry, there's more one way to solve your problem :) Don't forget to upvote if the answer there helps you

Comment: of course not. At a first glance it seems to be what I am looking for but need some time to adjust it to my needs. I'll add it to favourites for now :)

Comment: You are right. BTW, you'll be glad to take your time and adjust it yourself. Since it's not a ready answer, you will learn the concepts of the problem.

Comment: Indeed! 

And when I feel comfortable with that I need to adjust it to work with zend frameworks select object. 
But that's another story and most likely another post here :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility using a `JOIN` subquery which retrieves the volume by the `MAX(added_date)`:

```
SELECT
  l.code,
  l.plant,
  COUNT(DISTINCT l.batch) AS Batches,
  lvol.vol AS volume
FROM
  lists l JOIN (
    SELECT code, plant, volume AS vol FROM lists GROUP BY code, plant HAVING added_date = MAX(added_date)
  ) lvol ON l.code = lvol.code AND l.plant = lvol.plant AND l.volume = lvol.volume
GROUP BY l.code, l.plant
```

Comment: That did not work. It ignored the plant for which we have a product with two of the same batches, in this case plant A1 was not shown at all :/

Comment: @Josef See the change to the join `ON` clause. Added `AND l.volume = lvol.volume`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t.*,
        (SELECT  volume 
           FROM  lists
          WHERE  plant = t.plant
            AND  code  = t.code
          ORDER BY added_date DESC
          LIMIT 1   --Take the latest record for the plant & code
          ) AS volume                  
  FROM  (
            SELECT code, plant,
                COUNT(DISTINCT(batch)) as Batches,
                SUM(value) as TotalValue,
                SUM(value * risk) as TotalRisk
            FROM lists 
            GROUP BY code, plant
        ) AS t
```

Comment: That was better. Just remove the "," after TotalRisk. However, I need to do the same for the value even if that was included in my example. I thought I was able to figure it out myself when I had a the basics. But with this query it was not that simple.